# Why would one have to assume that the rate of evaporation has to be proportional to the surface area?

Tags: geometry, related-rates

The problem states the following:

A container in the shape of a right circular cone with vertex angle a right angle is partially filled with water.

A. Suppose water is added at a rate of 3 cu.cm/sec. How fast is the water level rising when the height h=2cm?

B. Suppose instead no water is added, but water is being lost by evaporation. Show that the level falls at a constant rate. (You will have to make a reasonable physical assumption about the rate of water loss - state it clearly.)

I understand how to do part A, however, in the solution for part B, it is stated that one should assume that "the rate of evaporation is proportional to the surface area." I don't understand how they came to that conclusion. The full solution goes as follows:

[THE LINKED SOLUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyylG.png)

Comment: [Evaporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporation) "is a type of vaporization that occurs on the surface of a liquid as it changes into the gas phase."

Comment: It's a "reasonable physical assumption" since evaporation is a surface phenomenon, unlike boiling which occurs throughout a liquid, but whether or not someone would know to make that assumption would depend on how much they knew about the process, or if they were given similar problems in class. Sometimes though, teachers teach certain material, like the techniques to solve related rate problems, but assign problems that require steps, like making assumptions about physical processes, which were not really taught in the course.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. Thank you.